# How do I create a oracle database patch list overview?

Tags: oracle, patching

I need to create an list for Oracle database patch versions for a recurring audit on patch states. It will check whether the current patch state of Oracle database meets the required patch state of a CERT policy. The list will be used by a licenses management and monitoring system that tracks the Oracle database versions by querying a view. 
Example:

```
SQL> select * from patch_history;
DIFF :    77 DAYS ACTION=APPLY VERSION=12.1.0.1 DATE=20151030 ID= 11 COMMENTS=WinBundle 12.1.0.1.11 PORT=IBMPC/WIN_NT64-9.1.0
```

The string: “WinBundle 12.1.0.1.11” has to match with the patch description in the list/overview. 
The current solution is to manually search for the required patch states on Oracle support website. Is there a way to manage such a list in better way? The list has to contain the Oracle database version, the OS: Windows Server, Linux, AIX and the required patch version and the dates. View link as example. The format of such a list is not relevant.

[Oracle patch overview list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMJHm.png)

Comment: The only way to know what patchsets are 'current' is by getting that information from My Oracle Support.  If you a developing some type of audit procedure to be used on client sites, then you are going to have to periodically review your CERT policies, and what oracle has made available.  Their patch set updates come out quarterly, so you should just have a quarterly task to check it, and build that info into a configuration file for your procedure.

Comment: Quick Reference to Patch Numbers for Database PSU, SPU(CPU), Bundle Patches and Patchsets (Doc ID 1454618.1)

Comment: Thx - the problem is how to match the information with the your oracle database. You can't find the information like "WinBundle 12.1.0.1.11" in the Oracle Support side. There seem to be no way to do some kind of variance comparison. There is no standard for reading out patch versions. The naming is also always different.

Comment: the oracle utility 'opatch' with the command parameter 'lsinventory' (full command '$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lsinventory' will produce a report that lists all of the patches installed.  I have a script (*nix only) that will run this across all OHOMEs, matching against the databases listed in /etc/oratab.  You could leverage that. See http://edstevensdba.com/shell-scripts/creating-an-oracle-inventory-report-on-linux/.  In any event, you may need to adjust your thinking on how to approach this.

Comment: As of November 2015 the version numbering for new Bundle Patches, Patch Set Updates and Security Patch Updates for Oracle Database, Enterprise Manager and Middleware products will start to change format. The new format replaces the numeric 5th digit of the bundle version with a release date in the form "YYMMDD" where:

YY is the last 2 digits of the year
MM is the numeric month (2 digits)
DD is the numeric day of the month (2 digits)https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=541496385557805&id=2061926.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=h1eir9xcs_4

Comment: Since version 12c there is a new view: select BUNDLE_ID, PATCH_Id, DESCRIPTION from dba_registry_sqlpatch;